# Call derived class function from parent class without knowing derived class

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

I'm trying to build a software with a parent class that calls the derived class function without knowing the derived class itself. I've been thinking about it without getting to a real solution. I think I should get a pointer from the derived class in order to execute the code using the parent class.

Here's what I want to achieve:

I have a parent class with a pure virtual function. The derived classes will implement said function. The parent class will also have a static function in which ( using a vector ) will execute the code of the derived classes function.

```
class Base {

    static std::vector<Base*> vec;

public:

    virtual void Test() = 0;
    static void Func();
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    void Test()
    {
        std::cout<<"hello";
    }
};

void Base::Func()
{
    for (int i = 0; i != vec.size(), i++)
    {
        vec[i]->Test();
    }
}
```

The problem is: I need to call the "Test()" function from every derived classes. But that has to be done programmatically since I won't know what other derived classes will be created

EXAMPLE:

```
//Base.h
class Base {

        static std::vector<Base*> vec;

    public:

        virtual void Test() = 0;
        static void Func();
};


//Base.cpp
void Base::Func()
{
    for (int i = 0; i != vec.size(), i++)
    {
        vec[i]->Test();
    }
}
```

My Base::Func() is going to be called at any frame.

At this point the "user" is going to create its own implementation and header files, like this:

```
//Derived.h
class Derived : public Base {
public:
    void Test() override;
};

//Derived.cpp

void Derived::Test() 
{
    //Insert code here
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

PS I would need something like the update method of a game engine. Just like the cocos2d update method.

Comment: what's the question? (this should work just as you described it)

Comment: The problem is: I need to call the "Test()" function from every derived classes. But that has to be done programmatically since I won't know what other derived classes will be created

Comment: Your solution is just perfect. It's exactly what virtual was made for. Did you try it?

Comment: Since you need to have an object created in order to store all of the derived objects just make `Func()` non static and call it from the object that contains all of the derived classes.

Comment: If you try the code you've posted, where exactly do you get stopped?

Comment: The point is: the base and derived classes objects won't be created. How can I get it to work that way?

Comment: You didn't post any code that creates any objects.  Please show us a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Your point makes no sense. If you have a vector of pointers, the objects have to be created somehow.

Comment: I'm gonna edit my question to make it clearer.

Comment: I hope I made things clearer now, sorry if it was confusing.

Comment: You *cannot* call member functions on objects you don't create.  How could that possibly work?  It's not even a meaningful thing to want to do.  It's like saying “How can I make people that were never born brush their teeth?”

Comment: If you see how the Cocos2d update method works you will see that you won't need to create the object, that's pretty much what I want to achieve

Answer (score 0):

If you need to derive a class to implement the function, there's no way to call it the way you want without an object. With a vector of them, as your code does, however, it is easy:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

namespace game{

class base{
  void add_to_vec(base* b);
  public:
  base(){add_to_vec(this);}
  virtual void test()=0;
  static void testAll();
};

static vector<base*> vec;

void base::add_to_vec(base* b){vec.push_back(b);}

void base::testAll()
{
  for (int i = 0; i != vec.size(); i++)
  {
    vec[i]->test();
  }
}

}

class derived1 : public game::base{
  public:
  void test() {cout << "Derived 1" << endl;}
};

class derived2 : public game::base{
  public:
  void test() {cout << "Derived 2" << endl;}
};

int main(){
  derived1 a;
  derived2 b;
  game::base::testAll();
}
```

For simplicity, I ommitted the code for removing the objects from the vector, witch you should figure out quite easily, too.

Comment: Thanks for this, it is just like I would do. I'm still wondering how a game engine as Cocos2d can call the update function without creating objects, which is what I would want to achieve and I've been struggling with this a lot since I couldn't find any solution that doesn't involve objects being created

Answer (score -1):

It seems like a use case for the CRTP (curiously recurring template pattern). Let's say we have a base templated under a type `T`

```
template<typename T>
struct Base
{
    void Fun()
    {
        ((T*)this)->Fun(); 
    }
}
```

What you do here, is cast `this` object to the type `T` and call the respective function of that type. Where does this help ? Imagine inheriting from that class, only you templatize it under your type (yes this is legal)

```
struct Derived : Base<Derived>
{
    void Fun(); 
}
```

This way you can "Call derived class function from parent class without knowing derived class", provided that the derived implements an interface "predicted" by the base. Eg if someone defined a new class `Derived2` you could write code like this

```
Base<Derived2> obj; 
obj.Fun(); // calls Fun of the derived object
```

Comment: Thank you for answering but, am I wrong or this doesn't work without creating the objects?

Comment: @user3772833 It does. It's a property of the type. Dispatching will be handled at runtime ofcourse but type trait query works as expected

Comment: Could you please show me an example without creating objects? Thanks

Comment: All this will do is invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: @5gon12eder What the [CRTP](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C++_Idioms/Curiously_Recurring_Template_Pattern) ?

Comment: You are casting a pointer to a `Base<Derived>` to a `Derived` and then pass it as the `this` pointer to the invoked function.  But this is a dangling pointer: an object of type `Derived` was never created.  There are also other downsides such as that you cannot store a `Base<Derived1>` and a `Base<Derived2>` in the same container except in a `std::vector<void *>`.

Comment: @5gon12eder `this is a dangling pointer: an object of type Derived was never created` : The cast is being performed inside the object; the notion of object creation is implied, since I'm "refererring to it through it". This is a well established, well documented, widely used technique. Dynamic binding is not one of its properties, neither is type erasure, but I can't see how that's affecting the answer since I never said they are. I'd recommend some studying on the topic, I strongly believe you'll find it useful

Comment: A cast never creates an object.  The `this` pointer does refer to an existing object but that is of type `Base<Derived>`, not `Derived`.  You are doing an unsafe downcast.  Try adding a member to `Derived` and output it in `Derived::Fun`.  You'll observe strange things.  (I've tried and I did.)  The CRTP is useful but this doesn't make above code correct.

Comment: @5gon12eder Maybe [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c14cf7d5ecbe81db) is of help

Comment: You were merely lucky because the member function did not dereference the `this` pointer which limits you to things a `static` member function could do equally well.  (Except that I believe it is even undefined behavior to call a member function with an invalid `this` pointer that is *not* dereferenced.)  Make everything `static` and use `T::Fun()` instead of the cast (because that's what's gonna happen anyway) and you are fine although I cannot see why it would be useful except for obfuscation.  Anyway, I think I'll gonna leave it at that.  Maybe others will have more useful comments.