# C++: How to call the derived (overridden) function of a virtual function without knowing the derivative class?

Tags: c++, oop, virtual-functions

Here's my best example:

```cpp
class base {
    public:
        base() {
            // constructor
            return;
        }
        virtual void bf(double val = 0) {
            // This shouldn't get called
            std::cout << "Default behavior\n";
            return;
        }
};

class derived : public base{
    public:
        using base::base;
        void bf(double val) {
            std::cout << "Overwritten behavior\n";
            return;
        }
};

base example = derived();
derived example1 = derived();
example.bf(50.0);
// Prints "Default behavior"
example1.bf(50.0);
// Prints "Overwritten behavior"
```

To my knowledge, I can't use a variable of (nor can I cast to) the derived class because I can never know what the variable's class will be. Ideally, I just use the function that gets overwritten "last" in the hierarchy chain, but it could be any function that overwrites the base virtual function ("bf").

I found an article that works [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27946692/call-derived-class-function-from-parent-class-without-knowing-derived-class), as I'm also using vectors and have a similar (if not identical) issue. Unfortunately, I can't have a vector of pointers. (SEE EDIT)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

namespace game {

    class base {
      void add_to_vec(base b);
      public:
      base(){add_to_vec(*this);}
      virtual void test() {
          cout << "Base 0" << endl;
      };
      static void testAll();
    };

    static vector<base> vec;
    
    void base::add_to_vec(base b){vec.push_back(b);}
}

class derived1 : public game::base{
  public:
    void test() {
        cout << "Derived 1" << endl;
    }
};

class derived2 : public game::base{
  public:
    void test() {
        cout << "Derived 2" << endl;
    }
};

int main(){
    game::base a;
    derived1 b;
    derived2 c;
    for (int i = 0; i != game::vec.size(); i++) {
        game::vec[i].test();
    }
}
```

EDIT: Yeah, as some people pointed out, this isn't really possible without using pointers. That sucks. Thanks for answering though, I'll search for a way to lift the limitation that made me unable to use pointers in the first place.

Comment: _"overwritten"_ => _overridden_

Comment: If you declare an instance of `base`, polymorphic calls are not possible - all you are doing is initialising a `base` by copying and slicing a `derived` (which loses the `derived`-specific parts).   You need to use a pointer or a reference to get polymorphic calls.   Examples include  `derived x;  base &r = x; r.test();`,  `derived x;  base *p = &x; p->test();`, or `base *p = new derived(); p->test();`

Comment: The point of inheritance and polymorphism is to have a common interface that you can use without having to know the derived type.  if you find yourself needing to cast you are missing the point.  With this in mind, your vector should not store objects by value.  It should store them by pointer.  You do not want to try to assign one base instance to another when they could refer to different types.  Attempts to get around this often lead to object slicing.  It's not pretty.

Store `base*` in the vector

Comment: if somebody passes a `base*` or `base &` to  you you will invoke their overriden methods, or if they are placed in a vector, you will get the correct method. The issue you show only arises becuase you are creating the objects.

Comment: _"Unfortunately, I can't have a vector of pointers"_ - Why not? Isn't [this](https://godbolt.org/z/xd9nfGqhz) what you want?

Comment: You really have no choice but to have vector of pointers (or some pointer type class such as. `shared_ptr`).  A vector of values of types with different member data is simply not going to work

Comment: Sorry, but C++ does not work this way. You cannot call a method in a derived class if, well, the derived class does not exist. And in the situation you described you do not have a derived class, only the base class. If you have a vector of base classes, that's what you have: a vector of base classes. There are no derived classes. They do not exist. You can not call a method from an instance of a class that does not exist.

Comment: Thought-experiment time...  Imagine you have a base class that stores one integer member, and a derived class that stores a string member.  Now, you have a vector of base _values_...  A vector stores these values consecutively in memory.  Now, tell us: where in memory will it store strings from your derived class, when the vector only knows the number of bytes required to store each base value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
base example = derived();
```

this doesn't do what you think it does.

In C++, you can have values of object type.  Such objects are the type they state they are, exactly.  They aren't a possibly derived type.

The above line does something known as object slicing.  Slicing is when part of one object - here, the base part of the temporary derived - is copied onto another - here, the entire part of `example`.

The type of `example` remains `base`; it is a value, and values have static type.

The easiest solution is to use a smart pointer such as a `unique_ptr`; this move only type manages memory for you, and permits polymorphic types to be stored (so long as yoh take proper percautions, such as a virtual destructor).

You can also write a `value_ptr`, a smart pointer that is no longer semi-regular but rather regular.

This will require a `virtual std::unique_ptr<base> clone() const` method in the base class, or similar.

Now this is not the only solution.  C++ provides a default object model, but is powerful enough to let you roll your own.

`std::function` is a value type that acts polymorphically.  And the techniques typically used to write std function are available to non-std library programmers.  This is not, however, a beginner task.

A sketch (and only a sketch) is that you define your value type wrapper with storage that can be used for either placement new or a smart pointer, plus a hand rolled vtable that stores the operations on the type erased value.  Then write a layer of glue methods in the value type, plus a template constructor that stores (possibly with type tags) type values properly (including creating the vtable, which can be done using a static local in a template function, and returning a pointer to it).

This is not intended as a set of instructions to follow, just a description of what someone can do.  If you want to follow this path, start reading up on writing your own std function, type erasure, and practice the simple techniques for a few dozen hours.  Then revisit tye above paragraph, and iterate on C++ type erasure examples for a few dozen hours.

If you don't have the time to learn a new skill, just go with smart pointers.  It is a lot easier.  And by the time you have a real need for hand rolled value semantic object models, [c++26](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b26) may be here with compile time reflection and metatypes, and the effort will have gotten 10x easier.

Comment: Sorry I'm over a year late to respond. I've learned a LOT about C++ since then (I did end up solving my problem), but I'm seeing this after opening StackOverflow for the first time in a long while. That answer was very helpful, thanks.